# Return the same instance type as the input type in generics

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

Tried this code:

```
public static T NotEmpty<T, X> (T instance, string paramName = null) where T : IEnumerable<X>
{
    if (instance != null)
        if (instance.Any ())
            return instance;

    throw new Exception ();
}

static void Main (string[] args)
{
    var list = new List<int> () { 1, 2, 3 };
    var t = NotEmpty (list);
}
```

EDIT:
So I want to pass any type that implements `IEnumerable` like `List<int>` and return instance of same type (`LIst<int>`).

> error: `var t = NotEmpty (list);`
>   The type arguments for method `NoName.Program.NotEmpty<T,X>(T, string)` cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Comment: where does the compiler say that at which location?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you don't need two generic parameter. You can replace `T` as `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public static IEnumerable<T> NotEmpty<T> (IEnumerable<T> instance, string paramName = null)
{
    if (instance != null && instance.Any())
        return instance;

    throw new Exception ();
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/BEekLp)